why private ip address need to use CIDR prefixs such as /8, /12, /16?
"The Internet Assigned Numbers Authority (IANA) has reserved the
following three blocks of the IP address space for private internets:
 10.0.0.0     -   10.255.255.255  (CIDR block: 10.0.0.0/8)
 172.16.0.0   -   172.31.255.255  (CIDR block: 172.16.0.0/12)
 192.168.0.0  -   192.168.255.255 (CIDR block: 192.168.0.0/16)

I have two questions:

since Network address classes are dead and we are in CIDR world, so we can use any prefix we want such as /9, /17, /25 etc, so why there are still "default" CIDR prefixs /8, /12, /16 being used? why not just define the private ip address ranges only without default CIDR blocks such as:

10.0.0.0     -   10.255.255.255    // no need to specify CIDR block
172.16.0.0   -   172.31.255.255    // no need to specify CIDR block
192.168.0.0  -   192.168.255.255   // no need to specify CIDR block

then we can do the subnetting any way we want such as
10.0.0.0/9
172.16.0.0/15
192.168.0.0/20


does the following ip range has only 1 network:

192.168.0.0  -   192.168.255.255 (CIDR block: 192.168.0.0/16)

since /16 prefix means first two octets "192.168" is for network bit, since last address also starts with 192.168 so there is only one single network that has 255x255 host addresses, is my understanding correct?

You write "since /16 prefix means first two octets "192.168" is for network bit, since last address also starts with 192.168 so there is only one single network that has 255x255 host addresses, is my understanding correct?" <-- i'd say 196.168 is the network field or network portion.  Not network bit! (bit is one binary digit).    As for how many hosts, you forget that there are 256 numbers between 0-255 'cos 0 is included. So u have 256256  And then u have to consider that one address is the network address and one is the broadcast address. So u get 256256  - 2. So i'd say 65534 hosts there

Also i'd note that it's definitely easier for a human to work with  if the CIDR blocks are /8 or /16 e.t.c. multiples of 8. But figures that aren't multiples of 8 are clearly commonly used too. I've never heard of ""default" CIDR prefixs"  The standard conventions for private IP addresses are from here https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1918

So IANA have already made a decision about what IP Addresses (what ranges), are allowed on the public internet and what aren't. Maybe it'd be tricky to change that. And the 172.16 one is 172.16.0.0      -   172.31.255.255  (172.16/12 prefix).  Most people use the 192 one and the 10 one , those are easier. Multiple of 8 prefixes.

Just because those ranges are set aside doesn't mean you can't subnet them. I don't get why you seem to think you can't subnet them (that is, subdivide them into smaller subnets). Please subnet them all you want!


why there are still "default" CIDR prefixs /8, /12, /16 being used?

They are not "default" CIDR prefixes – CIDR was what got rid of the "default netmask" concept that early classful subnetting had, so these prefixes merely define the available range.
If some old systems still have the concept of a default netmask, or a default prefix length, it's probably a 99% chance that such systems use the old classful defaults and not the ones you listed. Whenever such code gets eventually removed, the new default is either a /32 or no default (and the netmask/length is made mandatory) depending on what's more appropriate. I don't think I've seen any system default to 192.168/16 for example.

why not just define the private ip address ranges only without default CIDR blocks such as

Because they really mean the same thing, and the CIDR form is shorter to write than start-end range form. The private ranges are defined primarily as start-end ranges (implied by the fact that the CIDR prefix is in parens and the range is not), but since each of those ranges maps exactly to a single prefix, everyone uses the prefix for convenience.
It's for the same reason that prefix notation is used instead of netmask notation in most newer systems – both express the same thing but prefix is shorter.
Also, routing tables work exclusively with prefixes, so it would be more effort to transform a start-end range into a prefix whenever it is needed.
(There's also an advantage in making network size calculations easier – for every /x the formula is always 2(32-x), with fewer opportunities for the off-by-one mistakes that you made with "255x255" – even more so when you have e.g. a range of /29 or /14.)

then we can do the subnetting any way we want such as

You can already do that. Literally nothing stops you from doing so.

so there is only one single network that has 255x255 host addresses, is my understanding correct?

It would have 256x256 (minus two) host addresses if used as-is as a /16, but it can be subdivided into any combination of smaller networks (subnets if you want), in which case each subnet will have an independent calculation.
Note that there is a distinction between a route prefix (network) and an on-link or interface prefix (subnet). Reserved "minus two" addresses only apply to prefixes directly configured on an interface – not to routes; e.g. a /16 route or network has all 256x256 valid addresses, only a /16 directly on eth0 doesn't.
